# configuration composer.json Symfony3 and sonataAdmin

Tags: fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, symfony, sonata-user-bundle

I want to start a project with `Symfony3` and `SonataAdmin`
I was trying a lot of versions of `symfony` and `sonataAdminBundle` 
But I always get errors when updating composer

What's the correct `composer.json` to start my project

thanks

Comment: Hello, what error are you getting? I've been able to use `composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle` with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/admin-bundle) the current `v3.3.1` of SonataAdminBundle should be compatible with Symfony `^3.0`.

You can just run `composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle` and it will automatically look for the newest compatible version. If that fails you could try allowing development-versions as well.

```
composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle:dev-master
```

That should be your last resort though as it pulls in an unstable dependency. Feel free to add composer's error to your question and maybe I or someone else can give a more precise answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I have error when adding **SonataUserBunle**

Comment: [The packagist entry for SonataUserBundle](https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/user-bundle#dev-master) shows that it requires various symfony components in version `^2.3` which means it's not compatible with `^3.0` yet, not even dev-master (linked above). You could [open a ticket with the project](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues) if there is none yet.

Comment: Another solution would be to create a fork of the project, update the dependencies and then [use to that repo in your composer.json instead](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository)